# Symfony Zend Lucene connect two tables

Tags: zend-framework, search, symfony1, lucene

I have 2 connected tables with a foreign key. I want to indexing fields from this two tables into `Zend_Search_Lucene` for searching.

```
//example:
table 1 users:
  username:
  email:
  ...other fields
table 2 Users info:
  users_id //Id from first table
  first_name
  last_name
  city
```

I already have `Zend_Search_Lucene` on the first table but I want to search with all this fields.

How to merge first and second table?

Comment: symfony 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.0 or 2.1?

Comment: I use symfony 1.4 doctrine ORM